# Mysqldump Causes Error Establishing A Database Connection While Running

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-server

**Server Informaton:**

Mac Mini
Intel® Core™ i7-3615 2.3GHz QC
16GB DDR3 1600MHz
250GB SSD
OS X Server 10.8.5
MySQL 5.6.12

**Problem Specifics:**

Anytime I run mysqldump, including manually over the command line or as part of a shell script, all the websites on the server show 'Error Connecting to Database'. Sometimes after it's finished with a large process, the sites will load intermittently until the server reboots.

I have strict mode off.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?